# compressed a json data, angularJs

Tags: .net, json, angularjs

I 'm developing a web aplication with .net API and back end with angularjs restfull , problem I have big data json (4 mb) , is there a solution to reform the json data or compressed ? for optimized  the response time

Comment: Do you really need all the data? Can't you break them down into smaller pieces?

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to compress JSON data
1) Instead of Using arrays of object, try to use arrays of array

Ex:

```
[{"name":"qwerty","mobile":"000112233","location":"NorthPole"},{"temp":"0 deg","sunrise":"qw","sunset":"er"}]
```

to

```
[["qwerty","000112233","NorthPole"],["0","qw","er"]]
```

2) Remove blank space in json object

3) if you want to maintain array of objects. then reduce size of variable name:

```
[{"n":"qwerty","m":"000112233","l":"NorthPole"},{"t":"0 deg","r":"qw","s":"er"}]
```

My suggestion is not to pass large weight data in webapi. use async calls to fetch data which is required  on  demand.

Answer (score 1):

Other than using some minification library in your server-side code, you could setup GZIP compression on the web server itself. All browsers today support GZIP and will send `Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip` header, so the server would know to compress before sending the respone.

Here are links to setup compression on Apache and IIS:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771003(WS.10).aspx